# Java why java ftp uploads file corrupted

Tags: java, ftp

I'm trying to upload image to my server but when I'm trying to open this image - it's not possible to open, apparently because it's corrupted. Can someone help me and tell me why? thanks!
I'm using the Apache Commons Net jar.

```java
String hostName = "host";
String username = "username";
String password = "pass";
String location = "filePath.png";
FTPClient ftp = null;

InputStream in = null;
try {
    ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect(hostName);
    ftp.login(username, password);

    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/pictures");

    int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    System.out.println("Received Reply from FTP Connection:" + reply);

    if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
    {
        System.out.println("Connected Success");
    }

    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    File f1 = new File(location);
    in = new FileInputStream(f1);

    ftp.storeFile("fileName.png",in);

    System.out.println("SUCCESS");

    in.close();
    ftp.logout();
    ftp.disconnect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is the images the right size?

Comment: What do you mean? I tried to upload small image but the size of it even matter?

Comment: @Yael Please use correct indentation and [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) the next time you post a code fragment.

Comment: Is the size of the uploaded file correct? Is this so hard to understand?

Comment: And have you considered checking the result of `ftp.storeFile()`? Instead of just printing "SUCCESS" whether it succeeded or failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My antivirus was blocking it..